# avconv: create a video from a set of static gifs in a directory

Tags: linux, libav

I have a set of non-sequential gif images in a directory and I am trying to combine them into a video using avconv. There are approximately 150 frames of identical size (3400x1600). I would like to avoid renaming the files if possible since the names contain some useful data.

The wiki suggests the command

```
cat frames/*.gif  |/usr/bin/avconv -f image2pipe -c:v mjpeg -i - -r 25 -map 0 test.mov
```

which returns the errors

```
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] only 8 bits/component accepted
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] [IMGUTILS @ 0x3a1c4a91fe0] Picture size 50815x30051 is inval                                                                  id
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c6)
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c8)
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] invalid id 190
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] [IMGUTILS @ 0x3a1c4a91fe0] Picture size 43622x41252 is inval                                                                  id
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] only 8 bits/component accepted
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (ca)
[mjpeg @ 0x1c42ec0] only 8 bits/component accepted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: gif is a distinct format so `-c:v mjpeg` is wrong. And gif is not considered an image at all by FFmpeg/Libav,. You should use the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) in ffmpeg.

Comment: I don't have access to ffmpeg on this server. Seems like the best option might be to convert them to jpeg first and then create the video.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the `image2pipe` demuxer to read them in avconv.

For example :

```
cat filename* | avconv -f image2pipe -i - ...`
```